# Curl Redirect Hidden Content

Tags: php, html, curl, httprequest

So I am trying to get content of a specific webpage.
I tried using `curl` but as the result, I am getting redirected to a home page and I cannot retrieve information that I wanted from the page needed.

Whenever I use `file_get_contents()` and pass the URL to the webpage I'm trying to get info from, it works perfectly, but `file_get_contents()` doesn't work on the server and I am stuck with `curl`.

Is there a way to use `curl` and get `file_get_contents()` like behavior?

I believe the webpage that I am trying to get information from does it on purpose to encapsulate data and restrict the page content view only to people that enter their website through browser.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: if you are using chrome, then you can open up network tab in developer tools and request the page in your browser. You can then right click on the request and copy the cURL request.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting a redirect on your `cURL` you need to add this parameter to your existing set.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this function, you can change it as needed:

```
function url_get_contents($url,$ref="http://google.com",$posts=false){
    $crl = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    $userAgent  = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/28.0.1500.71 Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36";
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,  $userAgent);
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ref);
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    if($posts){
        curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($posts));
    }
    $ret = curl_exec($crl);
    $info = curl_getinfo($crl);

if ($ret === false || $info['http_code'] != 200) {
   $ret = "No cURL data returned for $url [". $info['http_code']. "]";
   if (curl_error($crl))
     $ret .= "\n". curl_error($crl);
}
    curl_close($crl);
    return $ret;
}
```

If you think it's the UserAgent, you can easily change that, or pass in a referrer url

```
$url = "somewebsitehere.com";
$contents = url_get_contents($url); #use google.com as referrer
$content2 = url_get_contents($url,$url); #use same url as referrer
```